# jQuery onclick either this or that

Tags: jquery, onclick

I want to check if I am clicking on a certain element or another:

```
  ((delete_box) || (man)).click(function(){ 
        overlay.fadeIn('fast',function(){
            box_2.animate({'top':'200px'},500);
            });
        });
```

With this code it only picks up the variable man but not delete box.

Any help?

Comment: pass the event object to the handler and check its target

Comment: sorry but I am quite new to jQuery how would you do that? with event.target maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$(delete_box).add(man).click(function(){ 
    overlay.fadeIn('fast',function(){
        box_2.animate({'top':'200px'},500);
        });
    });
```

or

```
$([delete_box,man]).click({..});)
```

Comment: In order to apply an event handler to a number of elements, you need to somehow create that group. You can use the jQuery `add` method which does exactly that, create an array of elements and pass it to jQuery or use a selector that applies to all those elements. What you did was to apply the handler to `delete_box` if it exists ***or*** (*that is what `||` means*) to `man` if `delete_box` does not exist and `man` does.

Comment: Since `$(delete_box).add(man)` works, I'm guessing the variables are just strings containing the item class/id to be selected? In that case `$(delete_box + ", " + man)` would also work, since it expands to `$("#delete_box_id, #man_id")` which selects both elements. Good luck!

Comment: @Jan, i do not know what `delete_box` and `man` contain. But they could contain actual references to the DOM elements or already made jQuery objects. In these cases string concatenation would not work..

Comment: OP says that the first piece of code in your solution works but the second doesn't. This leads me to believe that the variables contain strings and not objects. I just wanted to add an explanation so that OP understands why his code does/doesn't work. :)